# Adding control from winforms toolbox throws error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolbox

I am using a custom control in windows forms. The dll for the custom control is installed in GAC. I have added this custom control to my tool box.

When I drag this custom control from tool box to winforms designer I get the following error:

> Failed to create component 'UserControl'. The error message follows:
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0X80004005): Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a component.
>
> at VSLangProj.References.Add(String bstrPath)
>   ...................................

This works:

1) Adding a local reference of the assembly to tool box and drag it to the form is working correctly.

2) Adding a reference to the dll in project also resolves the issue

**Question:**

How can I make my user control appear in designer when the assembly is added to GAC? Do I miss any parameters in AssemblyInfo.cs file or something that I miss.

Edit:

On further analysis, I found that this error will happen if dll is not present in the provided location. For example if I add assembly from `d:\Location1\UserControl.dll` to the tool box, then this exception will be thrown when dragging the control, if I remove the dll from this location after adding it to the toolbox.

So, I checked whether this assembly is still present in GAC or not bu using visual studio developer command prompt and found the dll is present in GAC. But still can't find why exception throws

Comment: Having the dependent DLLs available in a place where Visual Studio can find them is of course a hard requirement.  Fumbling this doesn't normally generate such a hopelessly vague exception.  If you want to drill it down then start another instance of Visual Studio, use Tools + Attach to Process to attach it to the first, use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to force the debugger to step in when the exception is thrown.  The Call Stack window ought to give a few hints, do keep in mind that it is buried in designer code so it isn't necessarily crystal.

Comment: @HansPassant, it does not break on this design time exception

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario. I have made a new GAC tab in the toolbox, and I am dragging and dropping the dll from its' GAC location to that tab, not the original location on your drive from which it was deployed to the GAC (if I understood correctly). No errors whatsoever. Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938 SP1Rel.

Comment: Thanks for trying, did you check directory tab in tool box dialog which appears after clicking "choose items" option. The directory tab will display "Global Assembly Cache" if the control is added from GAC or a location to the dll if it is added manually